# Setting coloring in :term on urxvt

Tags: terminal-buffer, color

I use the [`URxvt`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Rxvt-unicode) terminal emulator, and `echo $TERM` returns `rxvt-unicode-256color`.

In `vim`, if I run `:echo $TERM`, I get the same result.

However, if I open a terminal window with `:term` and enter `echo $TERM` in that, I get just `xterm`, which results in a non colored prompt.

It is not that the colors are totally absent; for instance, if I enter `ls -a`, the directories `.` and `..` are colored in blue.

How can I have `vim` use `TERM=rxvt-unicode-256color` for the `:terminal` window, so that fancy coloring is available?

Comment: I get the same results.

Comment: Okay, my real TERM value is an xterm variant (`xterm-256color`) and yours is not so per the answer below that explains why I've seen, consistent (and unsurprising) behavior versus your experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected. Vim implements a terminal emulator for `:terminal` (since it needs to keep it inside its window) and it implements one that's compatible with "xterm" (since it needs to pick a specific terminal to implement and "xterm" is a very popular one.)

You can still enable 256-color support by setting `TERM=xterm-256color` in your Vim terminal.

See [`:help terminal-unix`](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#terminal-unix), which documents that behavior:

> **`TERM`**: the name of the terminal, from the `'term'` option or `$TERM` in the GUI; **falls back to "xterm" if it does not start with "xterm"**

(Emphasis mine.)

Comment: I have set `case $TERM in
  xterm* ) xterm='' ;;
       * ) xterm='TERM=xterm-256color' ;;
esac
alias vi="$xterm vim --servername vim"` in my .bashrc. Any thoughts about it?